# Hard disk detects but doesn't boot, CD ROM gets detected as MATSHITA rv10 downloader

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios

I started getting the `Select proper boot media...` notice on booting up my PC. I tried changing the slots on the motherboard, the cables, everything, but it still didn't work. I figured my SATA hard disk was gone. Then for some reason I had to unplug all the wires from my IDE CD-ROM and reconnect it to the motherboard again. After doing this, my CD ROM too gets detected but it is detected as a weird `Matshitarv10 downloader 1.0`. I figured my hard disk too gets detected. What is the problem here? Please help me.

Here are the BIOS settings showing that my hard disk and cd rom are detected:

```
http://s15.postimg.org/ngcch1g3f/IMG_20140317_150323.jpg
```

And here are the BIOS post messages:

```
http://s15.postimg.org/a1z9l09ff/IMG_20140317_150219.jpg

http://s15.postimg.org/9b6jf8723/IMG_20140317_150804.jpg
```

After choosing to boot it again shows me the `Select proper boot media...` message

Details:
AMD Athlon II X2

Asus m4a785d-m pro

4GB RAM running at 800Mhz (2GB x 2)

500GB Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 running at 7200rpm

Windows 7 32 bit sp1

No graphics card, using in-built memory, set to 32MB

Let me know if there is anything more I need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your CD-ROM and see if you can boot off of the hard drive.

I'm noticing on the second screen where it says "Press ESC to boot" that your hard drive is not visible.  I have never seen "SwDMA 0" in that field on any BIOS like the one you have.  Something tells me the BIOS gave up on boot drive detection after it encountered that.

Regarding your CD-ROM, here's my take:

- something internally failed and the unit is in some sort of firmware recovery mode.
- you were doing a firmware update and it failed
- you were attempting to install a hacked firmware and it failed
- you connected the ribbon cable wrongly (pin broken or missing on CD-ROM or board?)
- the ribbon cable itself is bad
- the jumpers on the IDE CD-ROM are set to some weird undocumented combination.

If none of the above help, replace your CD-ROM, or remove it and use a USB one.

Comment: No pin is broken either on the CD-ROM or the motherboard. I've noticed that my CD-ROM has no power internally, so maybe something internally broke up. Since if the data ribbon was bad, at least my CD-ROM would open up on pressing the button. No it does not boot off the hard disk on disconnecting the CD-ROM and still shows me the `Select boot media...` message. Guess I'll replace my CD ROM, try re-installing windows, and then go for a hard disk replacement if this fails. Also, can you do me a favor by replacing the links by the respective images? Thank you.

Comment: I'm also guessing by your comments that maybe the boot sector went corrupt, since you're telling me that something tells you that the BIOS gave up on boot drive detection. And since my CD-ROM lost it's firmware, it cannot detect that too. Right?

Comment: The BIOS would see the drive at that point even if it didn't have a valid bootsector.  It's weird that it shows up within the BIOS setup menu but not at that screen right before it starts booting.  Every BIOS like yours I've seen will display the hard drive on that final screen where it says "Press ESC to boot" irrespective of the bootsector.  So something weird is going on with your hardware.  Maybe a power issue?

Comment: Well that's weird. I changed my SMPS from 400W to 550W supply 6 months back. Never had any problems since. Anyways, what should be my approach now? Replacing CD-ROM first or what?

Answer (score 0):

The drive appears to be in firmware download mode.  Either you changed a jumper setting while you were messing with the drive to put it into this mode, or it is broken.  You might see if you can download the firmware loading utility from the manufacturer and see if you can reload it.